# Как найти все записи, id которых есть в другом списке

Tags: c#, list, linq

В общем есть SearchList и UserList, в UserList уже найдены все записи логинов и паролей по роли (делаю поиск Админ/Учитель), в SearchList есть список всех учителей ID которых может быть и не привязан к таблице пользователей.

Мне нужно в SearchList найти все записи которые привязаны к таблице Users (в UserList есть поле ID_Teacher к которому привязывается поле ID из SearchList, но связь есть не у каждой записи)

```
if (CmbRoleSearch.SelectedItem == null) { ShowAllRows(); return; };
        List<Teachers> SearchList = context.Teachers.ToList();
        List<Users> userList = context.Users.Where(x => x.Roles.ID == Convert.ToInt32(CmbRoleSearch.SelectedValue)).ToList();
        SearchList = SearchList.Where(x => x.Users.Roles).ToList();
        DGTeacherManager.ItemsSource = SearchList.ToList();
```

В коде выше мне подчеркивает красным Roles в предпоследней строке, собственно не знаю как выйти из ситуации. На что поменять Where и как сопоставить списки?

Прошу без нравоучений по безопасности и прочего, нас и так в колледже ничему не учат а диплом писать надо, кручусь как могу.((

Comment: А при чём здесь `Roles` вообще? Вы как-то сумбурно всё сформулировали. Насколько я смог понять, как-то так что ли: `SearchList.Where(x => userList.Any(y => y.ID_Teacher == x.ID).ToList();` Хотя всё-равно в целом как-то криво выглядит. Надо всю задачу нормально описать, наверняка всё это проще и короче можно сделать, без лишних сущностей, которые вы плодите.

Comment: @CrazyElf Спасибо! Заработало. Не мастер я описывать задачи, не отрицаю что можно сделать и короче, но пока и так сойдет. Roles осталась еще с прошлых попыток, оставил на всякий случай.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по комментарию автора вопроса, такой рецепт работает:

```
SearchList = SearchList.Where(x => userList.Any(y => y.ID_Teacher == x.ID).ToList();
```

Хотя это очень не оптимально по скорости и там вообще много лишних списков мне кажется у автора делается, но пока видимо и так сойдёт. Чуть лучше возможно было бы решение сделать `HashSet` из `userList.ID_Teacher` и проверять в чём наличие `SearchList.ID` через `.Contains`. Возможны и другие варианты, главное с чего-то начать.